# What is alternative to -dpkg for Mac?

Tags: macos, command, dpkg

I'm trying to use dpkg command but in Mac OS X it doesn't seem to work for me

```
dpkg -scanpackages -m . /dev/null -->Packages

-bash: dpkg: command not found
dns:Administrator$ man dpkg
No manual entry for dpkg
```

I wonder how can I use the dpkg in Mac??

Comment: Are you looking for an equivalent packet manager in os x or do you really want to use the debian packet manager?

Comment: @Lightforce I was trying to get the package for the .deb file so I can update the repo. but I thought mac also support dpkg command but that what I got in return once I input the command

Comment: @Lightforce : what is the equivalent packet manager in os x?

Comment: @displayName The most popular solutions are homebrew and macports. I personally use macports but some like homebrew better. It's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Or homebrew [Link](https://brew.sh/)
`brew install dpkg`

The macports version has a lot of dependencies and takes forever.

If all you want to do is see what is in the package then unar and untar it.

`ar -x package.deb`

You should then have a debian-version, control.tar.gz and data.tar.gz in your current directory. The files the package would add will be in data.tar.gz. The package description will be in a file named control inside the control.tar.gz file.

`tar -tvzf data.tar.gz`

Comment: I love `brew` It is awesome :D

Comment: Getting brew on OS X 10.11 if you didn't already have it is a huge pain in the butt. First you need fink, which you can't seem to get, as the OS X installation instructions are to use `dpkg`!!! UGH

Comment: This installation of dpkg is not configured to install software, so
commands such as `dpkg -i`, `dpkg --configure` will fail.

I got this error.

Answer (score 7):

You will first have to install dpkg. In my opinion the easiest way to do this is to first install macports which is a high level packet manager for os x and then use macports to install dpkg.

Installing macports: http://www.macports.org/install.php

Once installed you can run `sudo port install dpkg`.
Then you can use `dpkg` on the command line.

Comment: This has been the only decent starting point I've found to overcome my stupid homebrew installation issue due to SSL certs >.< Get MacPorts, then Fink, then cURL, then Homebrew... seriously?!

Answer (score -2):

"dpkg" utility can be provided by [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/download/index.php).