# a command to check if apr is already installed in my mac os x

Tags: macos, apr

Is there a command to check if apr is already installed in my mac os x? Please if anyone knows how to do it explain it for me. I started to work with command line very recently and I need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a program in Mac OS X (same for most Linux distribution), in Terminal, use:

```
which apr
```

if found, it will display something like `/usr/sbin/apr`

If not found, it will output nothing.

Note: in Mac OS X, you can use Spotlight to search. Much easier.

Comment: I tried which apr and there was nothing so I started to download and install but then I realize something else. I have mysql installed on my system but when I  try which mysql it shows nothing. When I am in /usr/local/ directory there is apr but when I use which apr it shows nothing. The only thing that it shows is sudo. On the other hand when I use spotlight it shows lots of things like it shows dpkg but when I type dpkg in the terminal it says dpkg: command not found.

Comment: `dpkg` does not exist in Mac OS X by default. Use homebrew to install `dpkg` if you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779597/what-is-alternative-to-dpkg-for-mac